# Plotly Dash - Python - Issue with callback function

Tags: callback

Please bare with my limited experience in programming. At least, I will elaborate.

My task is to create a Dropdown for a number of launch sites, and then plot the success rate in a pie chart. The user can also select a range of payloads with a RangeSlider, that will be used to create a scatter plot.

**This is how the result should look like:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omuiM.png)

**Here is the code:**

from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

URL = 'https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DS0321EN-SkillsNetwork/datasets/spacex_launch_geo.csv'

df_spacex = pd.read_csv(URL)
df_spacex.head()

```
# dropdown menu to choose from the various sites:
app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children = [
    html.Div([
        html.H1('SpaceX Launch Records Dashboard', 
                style = {'textAlign': 'center',
                         'color': 'black',
                         'font-size': 24}
               ),
        html.Label('Dropdown:',
                  style = {'color': 'black',
                          'font-size': 18}
                  ),
        dcc.Dropdown(id = 'site-dropdown',
                     options = [{'label': 'All Sites',    'value': 'ALL'},
                                {'label': 'CCAFS SCL-40', 'value': 'CCAFS SLC-40'},
                                {'label': 'CCAFS LC-40',  'value': 'CCAFS LC-40'},
                                {'label': 'VAFB SLC-4E',  'value': 'VAFB SLC-4E'},
                                {'label': 'KSC LC-39A',   'value': 'KSC LC-39A'}],
                                value = 'ALL',
                                placeholder = 'Select a site',
                                searchable = True,
                                style = {'width': '80%', 'height': '3px',
                                        'textAlign': 'left', 'font-size': '16px'}
                    ),
            ]),
    html.Div([
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Graph(id = 'success-pie-chart'),
        html.Br(),
        html.Label('Payload range slider (kg):',
                   style = {'color': 'black',
                           'font-size': 18}
                  ),
        dcc.RangeSlider(id = 'payload-slider', 
                        min = df_spacex['Payload Mass (kg)'].min(),
                        max = df_spacex['Payload Mass (kg)'].max(),
                        step = 1000,
                        marks = {0: '0',
                                100: '100'},
                        value = [2000, 8000]
                       ),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Graph(id = 'success-payload-scatter-chart')
            ])
                                    ])
```

```
# function decorator to specify function input and output
@app.callback(Output('success-pie-chart', 'figure'),
              Output('success-payload-scatter-chart', 'figure'),
              Input('site-dropdown', 'value'),
              Input('payload-slider', 'value'))

def get_pie_chart(entered_site, payload):
    if entered_site == 'ALL':
        fig = px.pie(df_spacex, values = 'class', names = 'Launch Site',
                     title = 'Successful Launch Distribution by Site')
    else:
        # choose the rows that have the same launch site as the one entered
        df_filtered = df_spacex.loc[df_spacex['Launch Site'] == entered_site]
        
        fig = px.pie(df_filtered, names = 'class',
                     title = 'Launch Distribution for ' + entered_site)
    return fig
    
def get_scatter_chart(entered_site, payload):
    # expand equals True to return a data frame
    # with seperated strings in different columns
    df_split = df_spacex['Booster Version'].str.split(' ', expand = True)

    # save the modified data frame
    df_mod = df_spacex.drop(columns = ['Booster Version'], inplace = False)
    df_mod['Booster Version'] = df_split[1]
    print(payload)
    # based on the input payload range choose the corresponding rows
    df_mod = df_mod.loc[(df_mod['Payload Mass (kg)'] >= payload[0]) & (df_mod['Payload Mass (kg)'] <= payload[1])]

    if entered_site == 'ALL':
        fig = px.scatter(df_mod,
                         x = 'Payload Mass (kg)', 
                         y = 'class',
                         color = 'Booster Version',
                         hover_data = ['Booster Version']) 
    else:
        df_filtered = df_mod.loc[df_mod['Launch Site'] == entered_site]
        
        fig = px.scatter(df_filtered,
                         x = 'Payload Mass (kg)', 
                         y = 'class',
                         color = 'Booster Version',
                         hover_data = ['Booster Version'])         
    return fig
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug = True, use_reloader = False)
```

**Finally, the error that I get is the following:**

```
dash._grouping.SchemaTypeValidationError: Schema: [<Output `success-pie-chart.figure`>, <Output `success-payload-scatter-chart.figure`>]
                Path: ()
                Expected type: (<class 'tuple'>, <class 'list'>)
                Received value of type <class 'plotly.graph_objs._figure.Figure'>:
```

I really appreciate your time guys.

Please let me know if I can provide any more info or help clarify.

I've tested the functions that take the user's input and produce the pie and scatter charts outside Dash, and they worked fine. So, the error is arising from Dash.